# jQuery: Set url params, append to it, add new ones and remove from it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm actually trying to build a filter for my page. First I've tried it with `$_SESSION` but I'll try too do it via URL too so to check what works better for me. The thing via `$_SESSION` was not so hard to program but now via `GET` in the URL I'm not coming forward..

---

***This is my plan:***

I've two categories on my website with an undefined amount of checkboxes in it. For example:

```
Color: Red, Blue, Green
Size: XL, L, M, S
```

Every value (like Red) is one checkbox. So in result I've two URL parameters which I need to set:

```
http://www.localhost.com/?color=
http://www.localhost.com/?size=
```

---

**Notice:**
After ticking a checkbox the parameter should be set to the URL without any refresh of the page!

Now it's getting complicated for me. Let's say the user hit's the site and ticks the checkbox `Red` the URL should looks like this:

```
http://www.localhost.com/?color=Red
```

So far so good. But the user decided to press `Green` too so I need to check if the param is already given and append the new value comma separated to the existing param. This is the outcome:

```
http://www.localhost.com/?color=Red,Green
```

---

When he ticks now a size, I've a problem with my current code because this code just removes the color param in the URL. So when the user ticks `L` I need to check in JS if the params exists too and do the same stuff like with the color so the URL must looks like this:

```
http://www.localhost.com/?color=Red,Green&size=L, ......
```

***Thought:*** But what if the user ticks the size first and then the color? So I need to append the params dynamically with `?` or `&` depending on the order.

***Removing the values:***

---

So let's say the user un-ticks the color `Green` I need to remove it from the URL so the URL looks like this again:

```
http://www.localhost.com/?color=Red
```

After removing the `Red` value the parameter must be completely deleted because there is no value left. The same thing must be done with the other parameters in the URL.

I've found the exact behavior for my filter on this page but they are separating it with a `+` which is not so hard to change `(By the way I don't need this for a shop so I can't use this plugin and buy it!)`. I've tried to analyze the `JS` on there page but it's a way to heavy for me:

https://plugins.yithemes.com/yith-woocommerce-ajax-product-filter/shop/

**This is my partly working code but I'm not coming forward now:**

---

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.filter-menu li', function () {
        var filter_value = $(this).find('.menu-data-inner');
        var is_active = false;

        if (filter_value.parent().hasClass('active')) {
            var is_active = true;
        }

        if (filter_value !== '') {

            if ($(this).closest('.filter').attr('id') === 'color-filter') {

                var filter_exists = checkFilterParamExists('color');
                if (!is_active) {
                    $(filter_value.parent()).addClass('active');
                    if (!filter_exists) {
                        history.pushState(null, null, '?color=' + filter_value.attr('data-value'));
                    } else {
                        history.pushState(null, null, window.location.search + ',' + filter_value.attr('data-value'));
                    }
                } else {
                    $(filter_value.parent()).removeClass('active');
                }
            } else if ($(this).closest('.filter').attr('id') === 'size-filter') {
                var filter_exists = checkFilterParamExists('size');
                if (!is_active) {
                    $(filter_value.parent()).addClass('active');
                    if (!filter_exists) {
                        history.pushState(null, null, '?size=' + filter_value.attr('data-value'));
                    } else {
                        history.pushState(null, null, window.location.search + ',' + filter_value.attr('data-value'));
                    }
                } else {
                    $(filter_value.parent()).removeClass('active');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

function checkFilterParamExists(field) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf('?' + field + '=') != -1)
        return true;
    else if (url.indexOf('&' + field + '=') != -1)
        return true;
    return false
}
```

```css
body {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.filter-container {
    position: relative;
}

.filter-form {
    background: lightblue;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
}

.filter {
    display: inline-flex;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.filter-toggle {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 55px 15px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.filter-menu {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    min-width: 200px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.filter-toggle:hover > ul.filter-menu {
    transform: scale(1) !important;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.filter-menu-data {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
}

.menu-data-inner {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 12px;
}

.filter-menu li:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.filter-menu li div::after {
    content: "☐";
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    top: 10px;
}

.filter-menu li div.active::after {
  content: "☑";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-container">
    <form class="filter-form" method="get">
        <div id="color-filter" class="filter">
            <div class="filter-toggle">
                Colors
                <ul class="filter-menu">
                    <li>
                        <div class="filter-menu-data ">
                            <span class="menu-data-inner" data-value="Green">Green</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="filter-menu-data active">
                            <span class="menu-data-inner" data-value="Red">Red</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="size-filter" class="filter">
            <div class="filter-toggle active">
                Sizes
                <ul class="filter-menu">
                    <li>
                        <div class="filter-menu-data">
                            <span class="menu-data-inner" data-value="XL">XL</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="filter-menu-data  active">
                            <span class="menu-data-inner" data-value="L">L</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

Can you teach me how I can to this better and completely? Because my code is still a halft of the way. Thanks in advance!